# What is the Mutex acquire and release order?

Tags: linux, kernel, mutex

I know the functionality of Mutex. But now I am confused about its timing. I specially mean in the Linux kernel code.

For example, we have 3 threads (let's say they are on the same processor and are all normal tasks with the same priorities). Thread 1 ,2 and 3 try to acquire the Mutex and only Thread 1 gets it. Thread 2 and 3 are blocked and go to sleep. Then Thread 1 has done his job and unlock the Mutex.

So here is my question: At this very moment, what will happen? Will Thread 1 continue to execute because its scheduled time slice is not used up? Or will Thread 2 acquire the lock immediately and start to execute because it is the second thread who wants to acquire the lock? Or will Thread 3 acquire the lock immediately and start to execute because it is assumed to run next from the task scheduler(Let's assume this)? What will happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once Thread 1 releases the lock, what happens next is *non-deterministic*. Any of the scenarios you outlined above are possible.

If your application requires a very specific order among threads, then you might want to try having the threads communicate more explicitly among themselves. In C, you can do this with a `pipe()`.

Generally though, the performance is best if you embrace the chaos and let the scheduler choose.

Comment: I do not quite understand. So you mean the Mutex unlock may not immediately wake up the threads who are on the lock? Then Who determines  which one should be executed next? The task scheduler?

Comment: @HaoShen That's correct. The scheduler will decide what happens next.

Comment: So I think Thread 1 will continue to execute because his time slice has not been used up when it unlocks the Mutex? Do you think this is correct?

Comment: @HaoShen There is no guarantee of anything. Thread 1 could continue, or it could immediately suspend in favor of one of the other threads.

Answer (score 0):

Once Thread 1 has done his job, he gives the MUTEX back to others, and goes to sleep.

Comment: There's no guarantee that Thread 1 will immediately go to sleep. It could continue to execute indefinitely.

Comment: @doniyor  Even Thread 1 has only executed for a very very short time? If it goes to sleep, who will be waken up? Based on FIFO?

Comment: I thought, after giving the MUTEX back, Thread 1 cannot execute.. ?

Comment: @HaoShen 'Who will be waken up' will be decided by OS Scheduling Algorithm

Comment: @doniyor  I do not know, that's the reason why I ask. So if Thread 1 has only executed for a very short time, maybe it's not fair to switch it out just because it unlocks the Mutex

Comment: @HaoShen it is also not fair to keep the MUTEX even if it doesnot have anything to execute while others are waiting for the MUTEX.

Comment: @doniyor If Thread 1 isn't in a critical section, it is free to do anything. Now if it were to attempt to re-acquire the lock after, say, Thread 2 got it, then Thread 1 would be blocked. But simply releasing the lock does not force the thread off the processor.

Comment: @chrisaycock oh yeah, you are right, i assumed there is nothing to execute other than the one in the Critical section... you are totally right