# Ruby - Using a Mutex to keep threads from stopping prematurely

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mutex

I am writing a Ruby application (Ruby v2.1.3p242 in Linux x86_64) that will repeatedly process online data and store the results in a database. To speed things up, I have multiple threads running concurrently and I have been working on a way to cleanly stop all the threads both on command and when an exception is raised from a thread.

The issue is that some threads will continue to run multiple iterations of `#do_stuff` after `Sever.stop` is called. They do eventually stop, but I will see a couple threads running 10-50 times after the rest have stopped.

Each threads' mutex is locked before each iteration and unlocked afterwards. The code, `@mutex.synchronize { kill }` is run on each thread when `Server.stop` is called. This *should* kill the thread immediately after its next iteration, but this does not seem to be the case.

**EDIT:**

The code works as-is, so feel free to test it if you like. In my tests, it takes between 30 seconds and several minutes for all of the threads to stop after calling `Server.stop`. Note that each iteration takes between 1-3 seconds. I used the following to test the code (using `ruby -I.` while in the same directory):

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'server'

s = Server.new
s.start
puts Benchmark.measure { s.stop }
```

Here is the code:

***server.rb:***

```
require 'server/fetcher_thread'

class Server
  THREADS = 8  

  attr_reader :threads
  def initialize
    @threads = []
  end

  def start
    create_threads
  end

  def stop
    @threads.map {|t| Thread.new { t.stop } }.each(&:join)
    @threads = []
  end

  private

  def create_threads
    THREADS.times do |i|
      @threads << FetcherThread.new(number: i + 1)
    end
  end
end
```

***server/fetcher_thread.rb:***

```
class Server
  class FetcherThread < Thread
    attr_reader :mutex

    def initialize(opts = {})
      @mutex = Mutex.new
      @number = opts[:number] || 0

      super do      
        loop do
          @mutex.synchronize { do_stuff } 
        end
      end
    end

    def stop
      @mutex.synchronize { kill }
    end

    private

    def do_stuff
      debug "Sleeping for #{time_to_sleep = rand * 2 + 1} seconds"
      sleep time_to_sleep
    end

    def debug(message)
      $stderr.print "Thread ##{@number}: #{message}\n"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you pare your problem down to one that can be reproduced in pure Ruby without reliance on any external systems?

Comment: I changed the code so that it runs `do_stuff` on each iteration. This simply displays a message and sleeps for 1-3 seconds. The code works and demonstrates the issue, so feel free to test it.

Comment: Thank you. That should help you get help. I would be surprised, though, if all that code is truly necessary to reproduce your problem at its essence. For example, is ActiveSupport required at all?

Comment: Good point. I slimmed down the code and removed dependencies to ActiveSupport and Singleton. The problem is still reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no guarantee that the thread calling `stop` will acquire the mutex before the next iteration of the loop. It's totally up to the Ruby and operating system schedulers, and some OSes ([including Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12784302/29470)) don't implement a FIFO scheduling algorithm, but take other factors into account to try to optimize performance.

You can make this more predictable by avoiding `kill` and using a variable to exit the loop cleanly. Then, you only need to wrap the mutex around the code that accesses the variable

```
class Server
  class FetcherThread < Thread
    attr_reader :mutex

    def initialize(opts = {})
      @mutex = Mutex.new
      @number = opts[:number] || 0

      super do      
        until stopped?
          do_stuff
        end
      end
    end

    def stop
      mutex.synchronize { @stop = true }
    end

    def stopped?
      mutex.synchronize { @stop }
    end

    #...
  end
end
```